# If I delete my Apigee API Bundle, is there any way to recover it?

Tags: apigee

Accidentally deleted Revision 1 of my API, now I don't have any revisions.

Is there any way to recover this bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer offline -- when it's gone, it's gone.

To do backups you need to remember to download your revision regularly (Project->Download Revision X) or regularly save to a new revision.

Comment: Another recommendation would be to develop your code offline, import and deploy it using a script or maven, and store it a version control system. This would reduce the chances of losing your bundles in this way.

Comment: True -- or set up a script to regularly download your bundles.  Trouble is if you're working offline you lose the contextual help and code samples you get in the UI, which are pretty cool, even if the UI isn't the most robust development environment.